# Clustered file system for storing large number of backups

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed, glusterfs

Need your advice in choosing distributed file system.
So, I need distributed file system for storing many backups (regular files, sql dumps, etc).
Ideal will be:

- distributed
- actively maintained (at least not dead)
- quick failover (for geographically distributed nodes)
- large community
- Open Source

So far I've two choices: XtreemFS and GlusterFS. First seems to be cool, but it hasn't large community and in generally develops slow (also it's Java-based).
Gluster - RedHat and other nice things, but the are some negative reviews.

Need help with this :)

Comment: Does my answer help ? If yes then please accept it otherwise ask away if anything is unclear

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try out Ceph soon :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [Ceph](http://ceph.com)
Its maintained by RedHat

Github link: [OpenSource](https://github.com/ceph/ceph)

For more quick info check their [FAQs](http://wiki.ceph.com/FAQs).

for WAN specifically : [Multiple datacentres](http://wiki.ceph.com/FAQs/Can_Ceph_Support_Multiple_Data_Centers%3F)